# DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories and EnumerateDirectories not properly handling question mark

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `DirectoryInfo` object that I am calling `GetDirectories("???")` on.

This according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383690%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should return all directories having exactly 3 characters in the name.

In this directory I have 5 subdirectories. 4 of which have 3 characters, 1 has two. This is continually returning all 5 of them. Is this a bug in .NET?

```
DirectoryInfo diBase = new DirectoryInfo(sProcessedPath);
DirectoryInfo[] diBaseDirList = diBase.GetDirectories("???"); 
foreach(DirectoryInfo diBaseDirItem in diBaseDirList)...
```

Also I found out that if you are in powershell and call dir (Get-ChildItem) ??? it returns the proper list of subfolders. but in standard command prompt dir ??? is also returning the ax folder.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: This code should work as expected.

Comment: @varocarbas Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: @dko: i think this code works fine but can you show what exactly `sProcessedPath` contains?

Comment: That's what I'm using, I've checked it many times, it is returning a directory called "ax" sProcessedPath = "D:\\GDM\\RawData\\2013_06a\\Extract\\eur2013_06\\osl\\mn\\tur" string

Comment: Does it return the folders with more than 3 characters or not?

Comment: no it does not return a 4 character folder.

Comment: Then I am afraid that it works fine. This is the kind of behaviour you should expect in GetDirectories/GetFiles, with "*" happens the same (it accounts for what you want and for all what includes what you want; for example: *.txt includes .txt files, .txte files, .txttttttt files, etc.). Shall I write it properly in the answer or it is enough with this?

Comment: but it doesn't work....

Comment: This is how it works. ? accounts for one character. ?? for one and for two, etc. Is it ideal/sensible...? It is how GetDirectories/GetFiles work.

Comment: "?" = 1; "??" = 1 & 2; "???" = 1, 2 & 3.

Comment: According to msdn, for each ? should equal exactly one character. So if you have 3 '?' shouldn't it only return directories that are 3 characters long? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383690(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The following wildcard specifiers are permitted in the searchPattern parameter.
Wildcard character
Description
*
Zero or more characters.
?
Exactly one character.

Comment: You can discuss as much as you want but this will not change the reality. I am explaining you how this part works. If you don't like it, complain to Microsoft. If you don't like the MSDN explanations, complain to MSDN, etc.

Comment: PS: you can blame MSDN of not describing the point clear; but what they wrote is strictly true: ? -> Exactly one character. what is true. You were the one assuming that "??" means exactly two (they thought that it was evident that means 1 & 2) :)

Comment: Anyway... Shall I put all this in a proper format as the answer or the point is clear already?

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer to this. If you call on powershell from within the program, it will resolve correctly. 3 question marks = 3 characters.

```
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell ps = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem");
ps.AddParameter("Path", sProcessedPath);
ps.AddParameter("Include", "???");
foreach (System.Management.Automation.PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
     Console.WriteLine(result.Members["Name"].Value);
}
```

This does not print out the ax directory name. So apparently Microsoft fixed their bug in powershell.

Comment: You cannot be so misleading. There is no bug; just how things are done in GetFiles/GetDirectories. This code has nothing to do with System.IO.Directory and thus is not a direct answer to your question. Please, update your title/description/answer to truly help others.

Comment: According to MSDN, all Get/Enumerate Files/Directories methods in Directory and DirectoryInfo say that ? is "Zero or one character in that position." EXCEPT Directory.EnumerateDirectories, which says "Exactly one character in that position.". This might be a reason for the confusion!

(Additionally, DirectoryInfo.GetFiles reads "Exactly zero or one character.", which is just a different wording of the "0 or 1" version.)